# Google Analytics click event tracker not working in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, click-tracking, event-tracking, google-tag-manager

I have implemented Google Analytics (`GA`) event tracking in Google Tag Manager (`GTM`) following these instructions:
http://cutroni.com/blog/2013/10/07/auto-event-tracking-with-google-tag-manager/

**My link click tracker is working** (i.e. everytime someone clicks on a `<a>`, an event is sent to `GA` and I can see it in the event reporting). **However my click tracker** (i.e. every time someone clicks on something) **isn't.** Here is my setup:

**Event listener**
[image]
[image]
[image]

**GA Event Tracker**
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Troubleshooting**
The Chrome `GTM` debug panel shows that it's working (i.e. every time I click something, the `GA - Click Tracker` event is fired:

[image]
[image]
[image]

However, when I look at the Chrome network debugger, I don't see the `__utm.gif` tracking request being fired, whereas for my Link Click listener (which is setup the same way), I do:

[image]
[image]

and my container is properly `PUBLISHED`, so I really don't see what's wrong here.

**Does anybody have any idea as to why my click tracker isn't working (i.e. why isn't the `__utf.gif` tracking request isn't sent when the debugger tells me the event has been fired)?**

Answer (score 1):

You are using tag type 'Click Listener' and 'gtm.click' in the rule. As you are only using it for clicking links , you can better use:

- Tag type: 'Link Click Listener'
- Rule condition: 'gtm.linkClick'

This is outlined in the GTM docs: 'When this tag is fired, Google Tag Manager begins listening for link clicks on the page. Link Click Listener should be used (instead of Click Listener) for clicks that take the user to another page. '